# iOS Manipulate View Controller instance from other class

Tags: ios, view

I have a sample `ViewController` with empty implementation. I create instance of it from other class and I want to add 2 subviews to it.

```
self.mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
[self.mainViewController.view addSubview:self.detailsView];
[self.mainViewController.view addSubview:self.masterView];
```

When I ask for count subviews self.mainViewController I see that there is 2 of them, but i didn't see them on display.
Same is if I want to change background colour for

`self.mainViewController`.

Any advices?

Comment: Have you set the frames for the detailsView and master view?

Comment: Yes, my output is like 'code'<UIView: 0x170161bc0; frame = (102 0; 922 768); layer = <CALayer: 0x17003ec20>>",
    "<UIView: 0x170161a40; frame = (0 0; 102 768); layer = <CALayer: 0x17003ec00>>'code'

Comment: Have you pushed or presented mainViewController ?

Comment: It is a rootViewController

Comment: It seems that I set up rootController in wrong way. If someone face problem like this it seems that the right way to set rootController outside of AppDelegate is AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app.window setRootViewController:self.mainViewController];